# error tf31002 connecting vs2008 with tfs2010

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008

I have the error tf31002 when i'm trying to add a team foundation server with vs2008. Errror says unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server.

I have installed all in the order that I have found out in the forum:

1. Visual Studio 2008 Professional edition.
2. Team Explorer 2008.
3. Installed Service Pack 1.
4. install the Visual Studio Team System
   2008 Service Pack 1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation
   Server 2010.

I have done that 3, or 4 times, and I still can not connect to a TFS 2010 server.

I'm working with a Windows 7 OS. I have readed all along different forums and I have tried a lot of things but nothing have worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you install the components in the order you listed.
2. Make sure you can access the TFS from Web Access.
3. Try to go to the TFS AT machine and connect it from VS to see whether you can connect it.
4. Make sure you are using the `http://tfsserver:port/tfs/ProjectCollection` url format.
5. If you use TFS server name in the URL, try to switch to TFS IP address. If you use IP address, try to switch to TFS server name.
6. Clean the Cache folder on your client computer. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`.

> Visual Studio/Team Explorer 2008 and Visual Studio 2005 are no longer
>   officially supported. To connect to the server, these clients must
>   interface through the MSSCCI provider instead. MSSCCI support only
>   includes support for source control integration and MSSCCI commands.
>
> Check [this site](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#visual-studio) of TFS 2010 support notes for Visual Studio/Team
>   Explorer 2008:
>
> Version control officially supported with MSSCCI provider. Version
>   control unofficially supported with SP1 and Compat GDR.